# Event not triggering on dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a table and in that table I have given a button to user in first column of every row to delete the row  and that delete button is dynamically generated when user enter the mouse on first column and this is the code

```
$('table').on('mouseover', "td.y-id", function () {
     $(this).append($('<a class="dlt-x" style="float: right; cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </a>'));
});
$('table').on('mouseleave', "td.y-id", function () {
    $('.dlt-x').remove();
});
```

and I registered an event to click of delete button like this

```
$('table').on('click', 'a.dlt-x', function () {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

and this event is not triggering. I look other similar questions and try all the solutions find there related delegated binding but can't solve the problem.

Comment: have you put this code inside `$(document).ready`?

Comment: I am using JQuery in Angular 2 for some purpose

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar that doesn't matter - the document.ready loads the dom as is - not with dynamic elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the event listener to `mouseenter` instead. Otherwise you'll keep appending that element if you move the mouse inside.

```js
$('table').on('mouseenter', "td.y-id", function() {
  $(this).append($('<a class="dlt-x" style="float: right; cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </a>'));
});
$('table').on('mouseleave', "td.y-id", function() {
  $('.dlt-x').remove();
});

$('table').on('click', 'a.dlt-x', function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td class="y-id">Delete</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td class="y-id">Delete</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are triggering for dynamic element. Use like below

```
$('body').on('click',"#dynamic_element_id",function(){
   // you code
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To stop appending the same element append if it does not exist

```js
$(function() {
  $('table').on('mouseover', "td.y-id", function (e) {
      if ($('.dlt-x').length === 0) {
        $(this).append($('<a class="dlt-x" style="float: right; cursor: pointer;">X</a>'));
      }
  });
  
  $('table').on('mouseleave', "td.y-id", function () {
      $('.dlt-x').remove();
  });
  
  $('table').on('click', 'a.dlt-x', function () {
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='y-id'>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='y-id'>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```